# The constructor Marker(MapView) is undefined ?? Why ??

Tags: android, android-mapview, openstreetmap, osmdroid

```
Marker startMarker = new Marker(mapView);
```

When I type this one to create the Marker is "new Marker(mapView); " red lined.
and i got this message in my headline -->The constructor Marker(MapView) is undefined<--
What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the OSMBonusPack, because it contains the right definition of Marker.
I had the same issue while following the wiki [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_1).

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.overlays.Marker
```

Make sure to download the BonusPack and include the .jar into lib inside your project and link it inside your project properties.

Comment: thank u very much...I work with this same tut and then the error comes

Comment: Every thing seems to be all Right and then I get in the console this one [2014-03-17 14:13:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/MarkerClusterer$StaticCluster;
[2014-03-17 14:13:59 - sfd] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/osmdroid/bonuspack/clustering/MarkerClusterer$StaticCluster;

Comment: i don't know whats this is, try to search on google and make sure that you imported `.bonuspack`

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the problem ?
```

It's because the constructor really doesn't exist.

Try this instead :

```
Marker startMarker = mapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(markerLatLng));  // markerLatLng is the position for your marker in the map. You can add more options to marker ...
```

Comment: public class MainActivity..this is my constructor and when i try this i have to create a class MarkerOptions.. I realy dont know what I am doing false